# .htaccess file rewrite second rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a rule for pdf files like
*domain.com/folder/directory/filename.pdf* would be accessible with *domain.com/filename.pdf*, so I've created this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*).pdf$ /images/qualita/certificati/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

It works. Now I'd like to do the same with another file that is in another folder, so I'm adding this second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*).pdf$ /images/catalogo/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

It doesn't work. It gives me error 404. 
And I think it's because the first rule. Even if I added the [L] flag, so what can I do to make all the .pdf files accessible like *domain.com/filename.pdf*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe double rewrite, like this (no tested)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*).pdf$ /images/qualita/certificati/$1.pdf

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^\/images\/qualita\/certificati\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*)\.pdf$ /images/catalogo/$1.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @grupowebex but it doesn't work. The first one does (adding the [L]) but the secondo don't. And, why the _\/images\/qualita\/certificati\/_ in the second rewrite? The files should be accessibile like domain.com/file.pdf for both rewrites...

Comment: i think ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*) is getting all the url context. When they go to /images/qualita/certificati/file.pdf and there is no file, it going to first rule again. Maybe a little subpath on first rule can solve this, to call files on domain.com/pdf/file.pdf

Comment: Ah, you're right, turns out if I put a little subpath on the rewrite both works! And I'll use this, the important thing is hide the real files path. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/qualita/certificati%{REQUEST_URI}\.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*).pdf$ /images/qualita/certificati/$1.pdf [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/catalogo%{REQUEST_URI}\.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]*).pdf$ /images/catalogo/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

These rules will check first whether the request is targeting `/images/qualita/certificati/` directory or not and then check another directory `/images/catalogo/` .

If you need to check first `/images/catalogo` make the third & forth lines first.

**Be aware that** , if there is same file in both directories a priority will be given to the first one .

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed, I really like this approach, thanks. But it still doesn't work, I'm getting 404 in both rewrites.